# Ideal of a Vanishing set $I(V(F[X,Y]))$ and how to repeat the computation.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ideals

The video I am getting this from is found here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=spHxUPvrkXw, it is around 5 minutes in.

The first part of the question is: for $F[X,Y] = Y^2 - X^3 = 0$ find $I(V(F[X,Y]))$.

Now the author says we have the inclusion $F[X,Y] \subset I(V(F[X,Y]))$  I don't understand how this works in that while I know that $V(F[X,Y])= \{X,Y \in K;F[X,Y]=0\}$ Where $K$ is the field, thus the vanishing set is just the set of zero's of the Polynomial $F[X,Y]$, but what is the "Ideal" of this? once I know that perhaps I will see why we have the inclusion above.

Perhaps someone could expound and tell me why the author pursues the following steps; the author goes on to say that this inclusion is really an equality, and he somehow gets this as he says we will take a polynomial $f \in I(V(F[X,Y]))g(X,Y) + a(X)Y + b(X)$  $p = (X= t^2,Y= t^3)$.

So I hope to understand

1. What $I(V(F[X,Y])$ is and what it means
2. Why $F[X,Y] = I(V(F[X,Y]))$
3. What he is doing with the business of $f \in I(V(F[X,Y]))g(X,Y) + a(X)Y + b(X)$

Thank you,

Brian

Comment: For any set $S$, $I(S)$ is the ideal consisting of polynomials which vanish at all points in $S$.

Comment: Thanks Alex. So I see that we are constructing this ideal - the set of polynomials that vanish at particular points. So in my case I would be looking at all the polynomials which vanish when their $(X,Y) = (t^2,t^3)$? If so, then I have all these "ideal" polynomials that vanish at particular points being equal to $F[X,Y]$ which are those polynomials $Y^2-X^3 = 0$ thus they are equal? So we could reduce/manipulate any polynomial on 2 variables (more if we combined them) in $I(V(F[X,Y]))$ to look like $Y^2-X^3 = 0$. Is this correct?

Comment: Well, keep in mind that any multiple of $Y^2-X^3$ will vanish on $V(Y^2-X^3)$.